# Click Event for WPF Image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, events

I am porting an old WinForms Desktop Application to WPF. The app GUI used WinForm's `PictureBox` to display images. The old WinForms app also had `OnClick` event handlers for all the PictureBoxes. Clicking the images actually did something important. Now that I am re-doing the UI in WPF, I found out as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559(v=vs.110).aspx) that the equivalent for WinForm's `PictureBox` control is WPF's `Image`. However, when I opened up the properties panel for the WPF `Image`, there was no `click` event to be handled, so I couldn't write a click event handler like I had in WinForms.

So, can you please tell me what can be done to achieve the equivalent of WinForm's `PictureBox` and it's click event in WPF? I want to display images and handle the case each time user clicks the image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In WPF each control has its default template (how it looks) but you can easily change these templates and make controls look like you want. This makes it easier to pick control by its functionality and make it look like you want. In your case you want `Click` so you choose `Button` and change its `Template`

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ImageButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Click="ImageButton_Click">
        <Image Source="..."/>
    </Button>
</Window>
```

With the above XAML `Image` will be your `Button`

**EDIT**

Below you can find simplified version of how to bind/change `Image.Source` where everything is done in MainWindow but basically in WPF you don't manipulate controls but bind their properties using `Binding` and manipulate these properties. Normally you would create dedicated class (ViewModel). Your class need to implement [`INofityPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, `DataContext` needs to be set accordingly and bound property needs to raise `INofityPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event each time its value is changed (that's how you notify UI to refresh value)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;
   }

   private ImageSource _myImageSource;

   public ImageSource MyImageSource
   {
      get { return _myImageSource; }
      set
      {
          _myImageSource = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("MyImageSource");
      }
   }

   private void ImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       this.MyImageSource = new BitmapImage(...); //you change source of the Image
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }    
}
```

and in the XAML:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}" Click="ImageButton_Click" Width="..." Height="...">
    <Image Source="{Binding MyImageSource}"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: Also, since he is using WPF, it might be better if he uses MVVM and instead of the Click event uses a Command. But that depends on what he wants to achieve. He said the click did something important, so it is possible that the Command could be a better fit.

Comment: So, we are taking a button and making it look like an image. Can you please show me how you would instantiate buttons of this style? Also, is it possible to set the image for the image-button from the handler of another button instead of XAML?

Comment: How use the button is already in my XAML. As for how to change image source it's also different then WinForms. You don't operate on controls in WPF. You create property with your image source (for example of `ImageSource` type), bind it to `Image.Source` using `Binding` and then you manipulate that property and not the control.

Comment: @StraightLine check my edit for example of `Image.Source` binding

Answer (score 45):

Just add a MouseDown (or MouseLeftButtonDown as suggested) event to your image like so

```
<Image x:Name=aPicture Source="mypic.jpg" MouseDown="aPicture_MouseDown"/>
// or
<Image x:Name=aPicture Source="mypic.jpg" MouseLeftButtonDown="aPicture_MouseDown"/>
```

which should add this to your code behind

```cs
private void aPicture_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //do something here
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest MouseLeftButtonDown is a closer equivalent, but this absolutely should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is not analogous to a standard "Click" event.  On Windows native controls, the _Click_ event (and _MouseClick_ event) is by default fired just before _MouseUp_, and only when the according _MouseDown_ event happened on the same control. That allows you to Change your mind mid-click and drag the mouse away to cancel, or back on the control to surmit. 
Also, we have to take buttons other than the left mouse button into account.

Answer (score 4):

For a complete clickable experience, I suggest using the CJK method with the Cursor property set to Hand.

```
<Image x:Name="btnSearch" Source="/Images/search/search.png" MouseDown="btnSearch_MouseDown" Cursor="Hand"/>
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the above method! And it works nicely, thank you.

Comment: Just a warning: Performing an action on _MouseDown_ is not in line with how Windows native buttons usually work. They fire on _MouseUp_, and only when the according _MouseDown_ event happened on the same control. That allows you to Change your mind mid-click and drag the mouse away to cancel, or back on the control to surmit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **MouseLeftButtonDown** would be more appropriate.